# What's the main reason that fewer people learn mathematics by themselves?

Tags: mathematics, university, academic-history

In the 17th century, there were some mathematicians who learned math by themselves, such as Fermat. They were amateur mathematicians, and didn't have a degree in university. But, in the 20th century, there aren't, and the only counterexample may be Ramanujan.

There may be two reasons caused this difference:

1. Mathematics gets more difficult so that amateurs aren't able to learn it by themselves. Only professional mathematicians have enough time and resource to learn it.
2. People have more chances to get into university. If someone wants to learn math, theoretical physics, or other science subject - he can easily apply to a university, and for talented students, there are full scholarship awards so he needn't worry about tuition fees. And, in the 20th century, before the internet was invented, the usual way for self-teaching math is reading books in library. However, the city which have libraries usually have universities - and they can just apply for it if they want.

The other problem is the concept of "amateur" is ambiguous. For example, this word usually denotes people who work during the day-time and learn math in the rest time. However, the situation is vastly similar to some international students who work part-time jobs to pay for their tuition fees. These students usually don't want to be seen as amateur learners.

Comment: I think this post should have been posted on HSM

Comment: Note that the last time it was possible for a person to know all of mathematics was quite early in the 20th century. The expansion was too rapid after that point.

Comment: Look at the mathematics posts at Arxiv.  You will find that there are *scads* of amateur mathematicians out there.  Even if you limit yourself to proofs of the Riemann Hypothesis, you will find many every year.

Comment: Comment upvoted for *Even if you limit yourself to proofs of the Riemann Hypothesis*.

Comment: @edelweiss, What does **HSM** stand for ? Please share a link ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

I do think that the premise (that there are few mathematicians nowadays learning math by themselves) is inaccurate: quite a few mathematically precocious kids, unless they have the unusual socio-economic-intellectual situation to be recognized and given serious support, will/can learn more things from books/internet than from typical school teachers, or from their parents.

So, I would seriously claim that any current population of the most mathematically talented kids will have necessarily taught themselves waaaaaay more things than their school, or even "enrichment" or "accelerated" programs will have taught them (or even *exposed* them to).

In particular, I'd wager that the fraction of the population that "teaches themselves" math is not so much smaller than it was 100 or 150 years ago, despite the drift in agrarian/industrial employment.

My mother's mother's father, a small-time farmer in rural Indiana in the mid-1800's, sent away for an "algebra" book, whose exercises actually included many Diophantine problems, etc. What strikes me here is that he farmed all day, but wanted to do math in the evening...

EDIT: oop, and, by the way, I myself "read" (in some sense) all the "math books" in the county library, while, in high school, being somewhat repelled by the culture of high-school math. Rules. Antique terminology. Disallowing complex numbers to explain things about trig functions. It was depressing. I did not quite realize that "math" could be a positive, forward-looking thing, until a few years later, by accident. I do still say to the grad students here at my uni, that "school math" is a bad perversion of the sense of math. :)

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago I thought about it as well when I was drinking with my friends, forming some stupid hypotheses to keep the conversation going. One of them was about economic specialization. This could be partially or totally wrong. I wrote in hurry, so I might probably provide some absurd examples.

Unlike previous eras, it is not easy to find someone "who knows everything" (relative to what people know nowadays). Even if you manage to find one, maybe you will be disappointed because they do not have deep understanding for things they know.

Does it mean that we get less smart? Absolutely not true. I argue that it is better for modern society to have less people **who know everything**. We have learnt that collaboration and **specialization** will increase our productivity significantly. Having too many prominent figures who knew everything was probably an indicator of a much less advanced economy/society.

In a particular poor pre-modern society, there was probably not much difference between those who wanted to learn everything and those who decided to become farmers. Of course, the former was highly respected, but economically they were much poorer compared to our standard, so it would not make a substantial difference no matter what you chose to do. There was no **penalty** (trade off) for not specializing as there is today. *This statement is clearly wrong and absurd as I could not give a good example to demonstrate what I believe.*

People did not have an incentive to specialize until specialization was "invented". There were forced to specialize by an invisible hand.

As time went by, the human knowledge increased and the society got better, but it also means that it became harder to master and have an influence over all fields of knowledge. "Good" people chose to specialize into a specific field, for example, **mathematics**. It was still very broad, but at least much better than specializing into maths, alchemy, philosophy, politics, etc. at the same time. Luckily for them, there were a lot of low-hanging fruits waiting to be picked. Doing everything on your own was not a bad idea at all. Maybe it was a good one. Welcome to the Age of Enlightenment!

Nowadays, human beings have accummulated a huge amount of knowledge about anything imaginable. No one is capable of advancing all the areas of Mathematics unless some truly fundamental things are invented, and it is hard. In order to be useful for the society, it is probably wiser to specialize into something rather than "everything". As you enroll to universities for your first degree, your second one, your third one,... you are **specializing** into something. You are contributing something to that tiny field, but we are, **collectively**, contributing to advance human knowledge.

When there were many low-hanging fruits, probably, it was not a bad idea to pursue research on your own without any guidance. A professor (probably G. Strang) said that "Gaussian elimination was named after Gauss just because he was born earlier". If I am not mistaken, Gauss did not invented it, but clearly, Strang was right. This is not to say that Gauss was not great (indeed he is undeniably one of the greatest mathematicians). You know what I mean.

Nowadays, you may easily get lost forever in the dark without a proper guidance (from supervisors?). We all need a good direction. No one wants to do everything on their own to reach a dead-end. Learning, interacting and collaborating with other excellent people in the field  will not only accelerate the researching process but it will also "gear" you towards the right direction. Doing everything on your own is risky.

Furthermore, in the past, going to university was not an option for many people. My current university is very old, and it was initially created for the rich people. They hired "professors" to teach them what they wanted. If you were not a wealthy man, probably your only logical choice was to do everything on your own.

Comment: "...He died earlier, too." - Gilbert Strang